# Redux Prop Passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

so I have the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    messages: state.messages
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch,
  ownProps
) => {
  return {
    handleSubmit: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // access messages as defined in mapStateToProps here
    }
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Contact);
```

thoughts on accessing `messages` (as defined in `mapStateToProps`) in the `handleSubmit` callback? or thoughts in general on how to go about accessing the props defined in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Have you checked `state` variable?

Comment: @zerkms typo! revised!

Comment: Are you using the `dispatch` within your `handleSubmit`? If not couldn't you just define it in `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: @ctrlplusb I would be, yes

Comment: I'd say you need to use a middleware that would inject the state into your action creator somehow, like `redux-thunk`

Comment: There is a 3rd parameter to `connect` called `mergeProps` in which you can consolidate props returned from `mapState...` and `mapDispatch...`.  Return the action and then combine the state and action into a `handleSubmit` within [mergeProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
    messages: state.messages
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps) => {
  return {
    handleSubmit: (event,messages) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      // access messages as defined in mapStateToProps here
    }
  }
}

function mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  return Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, {
    handleSubmit: (event) => dispatchProps.handleSubmit(event, stateProps.messages)
  })
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
)(Contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mapDispatch` function is not given the output of `mapState`.  It's a design decision primarily based on performance.  If you want to write dispatching logic based on state, you have a few options:

- Pass the necessary data into the callback function from your component, like `this.props.someActionCreator(this.props.someData)`.
- Use something like `redux-thunk` to write action creators which have access to the entire store state
- The `connect` function *does* have a little-used third argument, `mergeProps`.  If you supply that function, it will be called with the output of `mapState` and `mapDispatch`, and you can use it to generate functions that do rely on the output of `mapState`.  This will generally result in frequent creation of new functions, and could be a performance concern.
- The new React-Redux@5.0.0-beta version is a complete rewrite of the `connect` implementation.  Internally, it uses a new `connectAdvanced` function, which will be exposed as a new API.  You can use `connectAdvanced` for this use case.